# Lower bound of sum of cosine of angle difference

Tags: analysis

I am reading [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.11083.pdf) and got stuck at the formula above (5.13):

Let $n\geq 4$.

(1) why

$$\sum_{i\neq j\in[n]}\cos^2(\theta_i-\theta_j)\geq n^2/2$$

holds?

Note that this corresponds to the formula $$n^2/2\leq \|X\|_F^2$$ in the paper, where $X$ is matrix with $X_{ij}=\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)$.

Note that $i<j$, $i>j$ are considered separatly thus there are $n^2-n$ terms in the summation.

(2) does it also hold $$\sum_{i\neq j\in[n]}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\geq n^2/2$$

Comment: Any assumptions on $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n$? If not, it is already false for $n=2$: $\cos^2(\theta_1 - \theta_2) + \cos^2(\theta_2 - \theta_1)$ could be as low as $0$ if we take, say, $\theta_1=0$ and $\theta_2=\pi/2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I don't think there are any assumption on $\theta$ because see on page 19, the region of $\theta$ is $[0,2\pi]^n$.....

Comment: @MishaLavrov Would it be correct for larger n? let say n>10?

Comment: Are $n$, $\theta_i$, and $\theta_j$ all just arbitrarily selected?

Comment: @Dan yes assumption is just $n$ is an integer ($\geq 4$), and $\theta_i\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Does the summation count $\cos^2(\theta_i - \theta_j)$ and $\cos^2(\theta_j - \theta_i)$ separately, or as one term (in which case specifying $i < j$ or $j < i$ would be a clearer wording)?

Comment: @Dan $i<j$ and $i>j$ should be considered seperatly, thus in the summation there are $n^2-n$ terms I think.

Comment: @chloe: OK.  You might want to edit your post to make that point more clear.  Also the minimum value of $n$ to which it applies (because it's *not* true for $n = 1$ which is an empty sum, and not true for $n = 2$ because, as Misha pointed out, you can take two angles 90° apart and get a sum of 0).

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I just did

Comment: @chloe I don't think there's an alert that I've edited my answer, so I'll just point out in a comment that I've edited my answer to prove a tight lower bound. It is not quite $n^2/2$, but it is $n^2/2 - n$, which is almost as good.

Comment: Perhaps a proof by induction could work?  Start with the base case of $n = 4$.  Then assume that the inequality is true for $n = k - 1$, and then show that the additional $k - 1$ terms added by $n = k$ have a sum of at least $k - \frac{1}{2}$, so that the inequality is true for $n = k$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the unsquared sum: $$\sum_{i \ne j} \cos(\theta_i - \theta_j).$$ We can expand $\cos(\theta_i - \theta_j)$ as $\cos \theta_i \cos\theta_j + \sin\theta_i \sin\theta_j$. We'll be summing this over all pairs $(i,j)$ with $i \ne j$, but that's awkward, so let's add and then subtract the diagonal sum: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\cos\theta_i \cos\theta_j + \sin\theta_i \sin\theta_j\right) - \sum_{i=1}^n (\cos^2 \theta_i + \sin^2\theta_i).$$ We can rewrite this as $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \cos\theta_i\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sin\theta_i\right)^2 - n.$$ A lower bound on this is $-n$ (since the squared sums are nonnegative) and this can be achieved by spacing out $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n$ symmetrically around the unit circle. To see this, think of the two squared sums here as the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of the vector sum of $(\cos \theta_i, \sin\theta_i)$ for $i=1, \dots, n$; if these vectors point in evenly spaced directions, then their sum is the zero vector!

---

Meanwhile, since $\cos^2 x = \frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}$, the sum with the squared cosine terms can be rewritten as follows: $$\sum_{i\ne j} \cos^2(\theta_i - \theta_j) = \sum_{i\ne j} \frac{1 + \cos(2\theta_i - 2\theta_j)}{2} = \sum_{i\ne j} \frac12 + \frac12 \sum_{i \ne j} \cos(2\theta_i - 2\theta_j).$$
The first sum simplifies to $n(n-1)/2$, and the second sum (up to the factor of $\frac12$) is the same as the sum we previously looked at. (All the angles are doubled, but that's irrelevant, since we know nothing about the angles anyway.) So we get the lower bound $$\sum_{i\ne j} \cos^2(\theta_i - \theta_j) \ge n(n-1)/2 - n/2 = n^2/2 - n.$$ This can be achieved by choosing $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n$ so that *doubling* them mod $2\pi$ produces evenly spaced angles around the unit circle.

So, in summary, the lower bound of $n^2/2$ isn't quite true for any $n$, but $n^2/2 - n$ is almost as good.

Comment: yeah the $-n$ must be there because OP for some reason discards the diagonal term of the $\|X\|_F^2$